# Incremental unique number with PHP

Tags: php, unique

I have a list of clients that I want create invoice ID for them with PHP
How can I create a unique number with the following format:

```
NNNN-YYYY-XXXX
```

where

`YYYY` refers to Full year

`XXXX` refers to Incremental starting at 0000

`NNNN` refers to Client ID

ex. `2011-0001-2378`

Comment: You need to give details about your data. Where are you reading it from, and in what format etc...

Comment: I do store the $unique_id and $client_id in the database. and I like to reset $unique_id if the year changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just like that:

```
$unique_number = date('Y').'-'.$unique_id.'-'.$client_id;
```

where `$client_id` is ID of the client (eg. `2378`), and `$unique_id` should be based on the database values - you have to store the already assigned numbers somewhere, don't you?

Regarding `$unique_id`: you have to store the values for these somewhere (file or database) and to determine it you just search for the highest assigned, then increment it by `1`. It is pretty obvious.

Did it help?

Comment: I do store the $unique_id and $client_id in the database. but how do I reset the $unique_id every year? Also I want to make sure I am not overwriting the previous IDs.

Comment: @SwissChocolate: As I said: **store it in database**. If you do not store it, then start storing it. If you want these IDs to be 1) unique and 2) continuous, the you must keep a track of which IDs have already been assigned. Then it becomes _extremely_ easy. Think about it./